# total no. of different complete line sequences that can be drawn using n points in a circle?

Tags: geometry, circles

we are  given n points, 1 to n which are placed on a circle. we need to draw lines b/w the points. one point can only be a part of one line. we need to draw lines in such a way that no two lines intersect.
one complete line sequence is called if all the points are used to draw the line segments.
how can I find total no. of different complete line sequences that can be drawn using n points in a circle?

for ex: if points on a circle is 6 then there could be max. 5 complete line sequences.

Any formula which can be derived for this problem?

Comment: I would suggest, find the answer for 2 points, then for 3, then 4, and so on, until maybe you see a pattern, and maybe can prove the pattern continues.

Comment: I'm not able to find any pattern :(

Comment: Well, what numbers did you come up with?

Comment: for odd no. of points it will be 0

Comment: for even no's 2->1, 4->2, 6->5

Comment: That's a good start. Do a few more. I bet it's the Catalan numbers. https://oeis.org/A000108

Comment: I can't visualise. How are we supposed to create lines?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Your OEIS entry (the link) contains the comment ___Ways of joining 2n points on a circle to form n nonintersecting chords.___ so it is a pretty safe bet. Good reference.

Answer (score 2):

[Number of ways to pair off $2n$ points such that no chords intersect](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547719/number-of-ways-to-pair-off-2n-points-such-that-no-chords-intersect)
Is it the same question ?

If yes, then Catalan numbers is the answer(as mentioned in the post)

Edit: If you read the problem, its not directly related. N=3 in the redirected post is equivalent to N=6 in this post. Catalan numbers is followed for the even numbers, for odd answer is 0.