# combinatoric question about organized people in a circle

Tags: combinatorics

I have 12 people that arranged in a circle and 6 balls. In how many ways can I divide them for couples to play ball that no one will be disturb by the other?

In other words:All the people arranged in circle i want to draw lines between every 2 people in the circle so that there are not cut between the diagonals.

***Update:*** I thought more about it and the solution is exactly Catalan number of N/2,
this is mean the solution of this question is Catalan number of 6= 132 options.

What is a legal arrangement is on the right, and on the left an illegal arrangement:

[image: what is legal arranged on the right, and on the left the illegal]

thank you

Comment: yes sure. All the people arranged in circle i want to draw lines between every 2 people in a circle so that there are not cut between the diagonals

Comment: You want the [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). See this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547719/number-of-ways-to-pair-off-2n-points-such-that-no-chords-intersect).

Comment: @pi66 can you please be more specific with the answer. i read this answer but still didn't understand the solution. i didnt see they are using with catalan number...

Comment: Also see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347889/number-of-ways-to-join-the-points), which is again a duplicate

Comment: @RossMillikan thanks but still i can't see how its helping me...

Comment: "Don't understand" is hard to deal with.  The Wikipedia article has a derivation.  If you have specific questions we can help.